# Javascript Evaluation

Tags: javascript, html

This is a question in which I have to create a page with the below requirements.But eventhough it works, I'm still getting an error from the compiler

> testWeb(htmlpackage.WebTestAssign2): Have provided all the inputs correctly, but the ticket calculation is wrong or The javaScript method is not returning any b oolean value 
>   false

Movie Ticket booking

“BOOKMYSHOW” is an online movie ticket system to book tickets for current and upcoming movie releases across the city in India. The user can select the movie and preferred circle while booking the ticket and the system will generate a ticket to the user.

As an HTML5 developer, you have been provided with the task of developing one module of this website. This module should contain the below pages:

1. Book Ticket page – This will contain details that will be entered by the user to book train tickets
2. Thank you page – Thank you page appears after user successfully booking a ticket

The image provided along with the question should be placed in this section.

When the user moves their mouse over the image, this image should zoom and be displayed in a larger size (This should be done using CSS3 features)

·         The no of tickets should be greater the no of children (Use java script for doing this validation). Provide an error message in the alert box as “No of tickets should be greater than the no of children”.

·         Show date and time should be either current date or future date. (Use java script for doing this validation). Provide an error message in the alert box as “Show date and time should be either current date or future date”.

·          All the fields are mandatory (Should be done using HTML5).

·          Ticket Fare should be calculated based on the below logic. (Use Java script for doing the calculation).

o   Ticket Fare =  Fare for 1 ticket * # of tickets

o   Assume fare for 1 ticket is 200.

·         For children the fare of 1 ticket is 100.

·         Once the user submit the form,ticket fare should be calculated and displayed in the alert box as “Your approximate ticket amount is  INR“.

The JavaScript method for calculating ticket price should return a Boolean value.

Example: No of tickets: 4 No of children's:1 then the ticket fare will be 700.

Note:  Correctly specify the element name, as given in the requirement. All your html tags should be given in lower case.

> testWeb(htmlpackage.WebTestAssign2): Have provided all the inputs correctly, but
>    the ticket calculation is wrong or The javaScript method is not returning any b
>   oolean value
>   false

The complete code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Book My Show</title>
<style>  
figure {
  position: relative;  
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height:240px;
}
figure img {
  max-width: 150%;  
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
figure:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<h1>Movie Ticket Booking</h1>
<form id="booking-form" name="myForm" action="thankyou.html">
<label>Name</label><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter the name" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]+" required/><br>
<label>Movie Name</label><input name="moviename" type="text" list="movies" required autocomplete="on" > 

        <datalist name="movies" id="movies">
          <option value="Irada">
          <option value="Rangoon">
          <option value="Logan">
          <option value="Fist Fight">
        </datalist><br>

<label>Circle</label>
        <input name="circle" list="circles" required autocomplete="on" />
        <datalist name="circles" id="circles">
          <option value="Silver">
          <option value="Gold">
          <option value="Platinum">
        </datalist><br>
<label>Phone no</label><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Mobile # here" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required/><br>
<label>Show date and time</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="showdate" required><span id="dateMessage" ></span><br>
<label>No of tickets</label><input type="number" name="tickets" id="tickets" min="1" max="10" required/><br>
<label>No of children's</label><input type="number" name="childrens" id="children" min="1" max="5" required /><br>
<button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate(); ticketprice();">Book My Show</button>
        <button type="reset" value="reset" id="reset">Reset</button>

        <figure><img src="contactus.jpg" alt="Customer Care" id="image" /></figure>
</form>
<script>
function validate()        
{
    var z=document.forms["myForms"]["showdate"].value;
    var x=document.forms["myForms"]["tickets"].value;
    var y=document.forms["myForms"]["childrens"].value;
    if(y > x)
    {
        alert("No of tickets should be greater than the no of children");
    }
    return Boolean(y > x);
    var date=z.substring(0,2);
    var month=z.substring(3,5);
    var year=z.substring(6,10);
    var myDate=new Date(year,month-1,date);
    var today= new Date();
    if(myDate > today)
    {
        alert("Show date and time should be either current date or future date");
    }
    return Boolean(myDate > today);
} 

function ticketprice()
{
    var tic=document.forms["myForms"]["tickets"].value;
    var child=document.forms["myForms"]["childrens"].value;
    var Fare=(tic*200)-(child*100);
    alert("Your approximate ticket amount is "+Fare+" INR");
    return Boolean(Fare);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `return Boolean(ticketfare);` should be `return Boolean(Fare);`

Comment: @aaron Thank you..I've done that but still getting the same error

Comment: `alert("..."Fare+" INR")` is missing a `+` sign before `Fare`.

Comment: @aaron I think i've  made a mistake copying here. I have written that too correctly but still getting stuck there...Thanks for showing by the way

Comment: Can you edit with your updated code?

Comment: @aaron done...it is edited

Comment: `x` and `y` are not defined in `ticketprice()` so decide if you want `tic` and `child` or that.

Comment: @aaron I'm pretty new to these concept that is why I have no idea about it..Took care what you have pointed out...still nothing...am I making a blunder elsewhere? It shows that the javascript is not returning,,,I've tried returning true and false instead of  Boolean and is is still showing the error

Comment: Does the "alert box" actually mean the JavaScript `alert` or an HTML element?

Comment: The Question did specify about it to validate in the javascript part and that is why i have used alert box in the javascript part

Comment: Can you try commenting out the `alert` and see if you get the same error?